# How to loop a sampler in a thread group in Jmeter until a specific response value is returned

Tags: performance, testing, while-loop, controller, jmeter

I have to performance test an application which does a PDF to PNG image conversion. For that, I have 3 requests to be sent, ie, 1 POST and 2 GET requests. My requirement is to measure the performance of one the GET request which does the conversion part and downloads the converted PNG file. Note that this GET request that download the image is dependent on the other POST and the GET request which checks the status of the job. The full work flow in a nutshell is as follows:

1. Send a POST request to trigger a job to generate a unique identifier string.
2. Using the string value generated in step 1 above, the GET request checks the status of creation of a PDF document. Since this process has dependencies, the GET request polls until a status of 'Complete' is returned in its response. If the response status is not 'Complete', then we have to retry this GET request.
3. And finally, once the response from step 2 is returned as 'Complete', the GET request to convert the generated PDF to PNG image has to be triggered.

So 3 requests above are dependent to each other and has to run sequentially as the input for one is the output of the previous request. So we have to run this in the same order (1__> 2 --> 3) for the entire duration of the performance test.

I have tried using the While controller, however, the issue I am facing is, the sampler inside the While controller (ie GET request in step 2 which checks the status) is getting executed only for a limited number of times and not for the entire test duration.

The jmx file I have created is as follows:

```
Test Plan{
 Thread Group{
   POST Request sampler{ //step 1
     //stores unique string response to variable
             }
   User Defined variable (initialize a Status variable to null string,  initialize a counter variable)
   While Controller(condition '${__javaScript("${Status}" == "" && (${counter} < 4),)}') 
           {
          GET Request Sampler { //step 2
                Regular expression extractor to get the status from response and store to variable
                    }
          JSR223 Post processor { //to check if the status value = 'Complete', otherwise set status back to null string
             /*
                 String status = vars.get("labelStatus")

                     if(status.equals("Complete")){
                     log.info("Label Status is Complete"); 
                      }
                     else{
                     vars.put("labelStatus","")
                      }
             */

                 }//end of JSR223 post processor
          }//end of while loop

    GET Request sampler to download the PNG image //step 3

  } // end of Thread Group
}//end of Test Plan
```

screenshot of my Jmeter script:

[image]

Ideally for each POST request I make (step 1), there should be a corresponding GET request (step 2) which checks for a particular status in response. If the response contains the matching text, then have to exit the while loop and continue with the next sampler (ie GET request in step 3 above) in the thread group. This needs to be repeated in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As per your While Controller condition its children will be executed while `${Status}` variable is empty or 4 times, whatever comes the first.

I fail to see where do you update the value of the `${Status}` variable, it might be the case you made a typo and need to change it to `${labelStatus}`?

I would recommend using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) in order to check the values of `${labelStatus}` and `${counter}` variables for each While Controller's iteration

Also pay attention to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) as your last JSR223 PostProcessor is being executed after **every** sampler in the Thread Group and this is something you might want to change.

Comment: yes sorry, that variable name was a typo. Thanks a lot @Dmitri T. I will try the debug sampler and see what the values being passed are.

Comment: So I used the debug sampler and noticed that the JSR223 Post processor inside the while loop is not getting executed. I think that's one issue to be resolved.